# iOS How to get the background dispatch queue completed Status

Tags: ios

I have created A Queue like this

```
dispatch_queue_t myBackgroundQueue;
  myBackgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.google.task", NULL);


  dispatch_async(myBackgroundQueue, ^(void) {
  });
```

this will be called on button click and i would like to know the current background running queues. Thank

Comment: What do you mean when saying 'would like to know the current background running queues' ? Could you describe what do you expect in result?

Comment: @Konstantin: Yes i would like to know the current running/pending total background queues.

Comment: You have only one queue, do you need to know count of tasks in it?

Comment: @Konstantin: Yes i have only one queue which is called on button click. In my application i'm calling API in background queue, Here user can click multiple times on button to perform action, I would like to know the status of background queues .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    BOOL ok = // some result

    // do some long running processing here

    // Check that there was not a nil handler passed.
    if( completionHandler )
    {
        // This assumes ARC. If no ARC, copy and autorelease the Block.
        [completionHandler performSelector:@selector(rmaddy_callBlockWithBOOL:)
                                  onThread:origThread
                                withObject:@(ok)    // or [NSNumber numberWithBool:ok]
                             waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
    });
});
```